# sql - filtering with a condition so there is only one row per date

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I'm trying to join a dataset that has many dates for many IDs AND many rows for the same date even, with one that has many dates for many IDs.

Let's call this one `Data1`

```
ID | Date       | PostDate1  | PostDate2 
01 | 01/01/2020 | 02/01/2020 | 03/01/2020
01 | 06/01/2020 | 07/01/2020 | 08/01/2020
02 | 02/01/2020 | 03/01/2020 | 04/01/2020
02 | 03/01/2020 | 04/01/2020 | 05/01/2020
```

And this is `Data2`

```
ID | Date       | Code
01 | 01/01/2020 | AA
01 | 01/01/2020 | .
01 | 02/01/2020 | BB
01 | 02/01/2020 | AA
01 | 04/01/2020 | BB
01 | 07/01/2020 | .
01 | 07/01/2020 | BB
01 | 07/01/2020 | . 
01 | 08/01/2020 | AA
02 | 03/01/2020 | .
02 | 03/01/2020 | AA
02 | 04/01/2020 | AA
02 | 04/01/2020 | BB
03 | 04/01/2020 | .
```

I want to merge them so that there is only one value in `PostCode1` and `PostCode2`.
It would be like this:

```
ID | Date       | PostDate1  | PostDate2  | PostCode1 | Postcode2 
01 | 01/01/2020 | 02/01/2020 | 03/01/2020 | BB        | .
01 | 06/01/2020 | 07/01/2020 | 08/01/2020 | BB        | AA
02 | 02/01/2020 | 03/01/2020 | 04/01/2020 | AA        | BB
02 | 03/01/2020 | 04/01/2020 | 05/01/2020 | BB        | .
```

However this is just an example, I'm not sure on the condition, that is, I'm not sure if I want to pick:

-the first one alphabetically

-the last one alphabetically

-any if it's not missing

-a specific one if it exists in that date, and if it doesn't then any

Could it be possible to create a code in which I could easily change part of it according to the condition I want to apply?

The code I'm currently using for joining is:

```
proc sql;
create table new as
select distinct a.*
, data2_1.code as PostCode1
, data2_2.code as PostCode2

from data1 a 
left join data2 data2_1
on a.id=data2.id and a.postdate1=data2.date

from data1 a 
left join data2 data2_2
on a.id=data2.id and a.postdate2=data2.date
```

And this currently returns as many rows are there are codes for each date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not syntactically correct.  I think the logic you want is simply:

```
select a.*, data2_1.code as PostCode1, data2_2.code as PostCode2
from data1 a left join
     (select d.id, d.date, max(code) as code
      from data2 d
      group by d.id, d.date
     ) data2_1
     on a.id = data2.id and a.postdate1 = data2.date left join
     (select d.id, d.date, max(code) as code
      from data2 d
      group by d.id, d.date
     ) data2_2
     on a.id = data2.id and a.postdate2 = data2.date;
```

Note that your question doesn't specify how to choose *which* code when there are multiple codes.  This just uses the maximum value.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I would like to be able to chage it, to the max alphabetically, the min, and also if thre is a "BB" code, output that, else whatever. Actually I just tried the code with max() and it's not working, still duplicating rows. Maybe because max() looks for numbers instead of letters?

Comment: @amestrian . . . This *cannot* be duplicating rows in `data1` because the `join` condition is guaranteed to match at most one row from each subquery due to the `group by`.

Comment: ah you're right, found a typo that was not letting it work. Does max() grab the highest alphabetically? Or just the last one (which is mostly random in this case since there is no time)?

Comment: @amestrian . . . `max()` returns the highest one alphabetically when applies to strings.